# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment in imported function only

Tags: python, mysql

I have written a function that should import data from a mysql database into python. The function works when I run it in the file containing the function, but when I try to import the function into  another python file I get the "Unbound LocalError" Error.

I have already tried to declare the variable 'sqlcode_sm' as global but it does not solve the issue.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymysql 
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb as mdb
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys


def sec_master_retriever(tables):
    # should be any column(s) or * for all

    sql_table       = "sec_master"


    ######SQL PART: Retrieving the data
    # Connect to the MySQL instance
    db_host = 'localhost'
    db_user = 'root'
    db_pass = 'xyz'
    db_name = 'securities_master'
    con = mdb.connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name)
    sqlcode_sm = """SELECT %s FROM %s AS sm ;""" % (tables, sql_table)
    sqltable       = pd.read_sql_query(sqlcode_sm, con=con)

    return sqltable
```

if I now continue and write:

```
df = sec_master_retriever('*')
```

This works without an issue, but opening a new Python file, importing the function and  executing it as below:

```
from sec_master_retriever import sec_master_retriever as smr
df2 = smr("*")
```

Results in the error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sqlcode_sm' referenced before assignment"

Thanks for your help

Comment: thanks this has solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

either inside

```
def sec_master...
```

or below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```